# Are there more meteorological catastrophic events due to climate change?

Tags: meteorology, climate-change, climate, storms, mesoscale-meteorology

I was told by a sedimentologist there is no evidence of more climatic catastrophic events at the geological register previous to Pleistocene, when climate was warmer.

My question is if meteorologists are showing an increase of this events due to climate change.
Are there more hurricans, big storms, suden inundations etc than before our emission of green-house gasses, or conversely the frequence of those events has stayed constant the last centuries?